# Downloader Middleware to ignore all requests to a certain URL in scrapy

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to define a custom downloader middleware in Scrapy to ignore all requests to a particular URL (these requests are redirected from other URLs, so I can't filter them out when I generate the requests in the first place).

I have the following code, the idea of which is to catch this at the response processing stage (as I'm not exactly sure how requests redirecting to other requests works), check the URL, and if it matches the one I'm trying to filter out then return an IgnoreRequest exception, if not, return the response as usual so that it can continue to be processed.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log

class CustomDownloaderMiddleware:

    def process_response(request, response, spider):
        log.msg("In Middleware " + response.url, level=log.WARNING)
        if response.url == "http://www.achurchnearyou.com//":
            return IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            return response
```

and I add this to the dict of middlewares:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'acny.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware': 650
}
```

with a value of 650, which should - I think - make it run directly after the RedirectMiddleware.

However, when I run the crawler, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.achurchnearyou.com/venue.php?V=00001>: process_response() got multiple values for keyword argument 'request'
```

This error is occurring on the very first page crawled, and I can't work out why it is occurring - I think I've followed what the manual said to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should raise IgnoreRequest, instead of returning it. Not sure if this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Shane: I've tried it both ways, and both give the same error. The documentation (at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response) mixes the words 'return' and 'raise' - so it is a little confusing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution to my own problem - it was a silly mistake with creating the class and method in Python. The code above needs to be:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log

class CustomDownloaderMiddleware(object):

   def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
       log.msg("In Middleware " + response.url, level=log.WARNING)
       if response.url == "http://www.achurchnearyou.com//":
           raise IgnoreRequest()
       else:
           return response
```

That is, there needs to be a `self` parameter for the method as the first parameter, and the class needs to inherit from `object`.

Comment: This looks good, except that you can't return IgnoreRequest, instead you have to use: raise IgnoreRequest("message goes here")

Comment: Why does this answer have so many upvotes?  Wouldn't this be considered a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which requests are redirected to the problematic ones, how about something like:

```
def parse_requests(self, response):
    ....
    meta = {'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]}
    callback = 'process_redirects'
    yield Request(url, callback=callback, meta=meta, ...)

def process_redirects(self, response):
    url = response.headers['location']
    if url is no good:
        return
    else:
        ...
```

This way you avoid downloading useless responses.

And you can always define your own custom redirect middleware.